# How is it possible Zerg,  with the biggest advantage, can still lose to Terran?

Tags: starcraft-2

[This replay](http://sc2rep.net/replays/starcraft-2-replay-t-tarson-vs-z-bly-xelnaga-caverns-10-30-2010) exlains it all. `T` **Tarson** versus `Z` **Bly** play on *Xel'Naga Caverns*.

Bly destroys Tarson's expansion, and pushes into his base, does a TON of damage, and kills all his SCV except for 2. Then he retreats, to defend against Tarson's final push (since it's his only choice at this time). The Bly now has two expansions, an army, more used supply, while Tarson has only his army, and almost no economy. But guess what, Terran is able to wipe out whole Zerg army and both of his bases, while still having a sizable force in the end (look at the units tab).

*I don't want to flame, but I just find the Marauders too strong. They are almost perfect counter against Banelings, since they have Concussive Shells (and Marauders will shoot the first Banelings they see, so in reality it will usually slow down the whole "Baneling train"), are armored, and have 125 XP. So when Terran sees Banelings comming, he just has to pull his Marines few meters behind his Marauderes. This way, Banelings will explode only on his Marauders, because not a single one is able to get it that far to hit Marines (30 HP is really ridiculous). And I think this is what caused the Terran to win that match, while he should loose. Roaches are also countered by Marauders, and mass Zerglings are countered by those Marines.*

So what the Bly should have done differently in this match to be able to defend himself against that final push? If it wasn't possible to defend against it, what should he have done differently to win that match?

Comment: Because of Marines: http://i.imgur.com/g5d3v.jpg

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do you want to know how someone can lose or how he did lose?

Bly lost because he played very poorly: **he did not build enough drones**.

Take a moment to let that sink in, because its a very very big mistake and its the difference between a good Zerg player (like Fruit Seller) and a bad Zerg player (like Bly).

Instead of backing off after taking the Terran Natural, he continued to press in.  He sends wave after wave of a consistently sized army.  He does this because he's not building more drones so he cannot afford a larger army.  By comparison Tarson's army gets larger and larger after every wave.  He's able to continue to accumulate units because he has a fairly healthy economy.  This is due in part to MULEs, but largely because Tarson built enough SCVs.  Even after losing his Expo he still has as many workers as Bly does.  Think about that for a second.  He lose an entire base and all his workers in it and he still has more workers than his opponent.

This game could have easily been one that was featured on [Day 9's Newbie Tuesday](http://vodpod.com/watch/4605299-day9-daily-194-newbie-tuesday-drone-timing)

I could point out a dozen mistakes that Bly made, but none of them matter nearly as much as his poor drone usage.  Because of his lack of drones, his assault becomes almost an all in.  So in response to your question `How is it possible Zerg with biggest advantage can still loose to Terran?` Bly didn't have a big advantage.  He sacrificed his economy on a gamble and it didn't pay off.

But let's imagine another universe, where Tarson wasn't playing Bly but was playing against a better Zerg like IdrA; and let's assume IdrA made the same early push.

Now IdrA is sitting on 2 bases to Tarson's 1, but they have equal workers.  So instead of continually pressing his advantage, IdrA decides to play like he always does: Macro.  He sits back and takes a third base and powers drones.  Tarson retakes his natural and now he's down 2 to 3 bases.  Not a big advantage for IdrA, but remember a Zerg can make drones faster than a Terran, so it takes Tarson longer to saturate that 1 base than it does for IdrA to saturate his 3.  Now IdrA has a huge economy and he goes Roach/Hydra (or these days he's favoring Muta/ling, but pretend).

Imagine that battle for a second... or don't, because it actually happened.  IdrA knocked out Tarson in IEM, exactly like I described.

The smartest thing you can do in Starcraft if you are ahead is to **get more ahead**.  Anyone who played seriously in Broodwars knows this because if you pressed like Bly did, you got destroyed 100% of the time.  Now Starcraft 2 is still new so a lot of people feel like they can do crazy 2 base play, but if you look at the high end GSL matches you see less of that and more of people trying to get *more ahead*.

---

You also mentioned a quote talking about Marauders vs Banelings.  Now I don't think that the relationship between these two units had anything to do with this loss, but let's talk about them for a second.

Banelings are a highly specialized unit.  Their role is to act as Zerg splash damage on light units.  By comparison the Marauder is a more generalized unit, designed to act as a Meat shield (much the way the Roach acts for the Zerg).  So it makes sense that a Baneling doesn't function well against Marauders (as that's not their role), and it also makes sense that Marauders do a good job of preventing Banelings from striking other units (as that's their role).

I would hesitate to say that a unit is broken because its functioning in its role and another unit isn't functioning in something outside its role.  But let's say you want a way to deal with MMM balls.  Instead of sending it waves of Banelings on their own.  Consider mixing in more Zerglings (Bly actually does this to large effect).  Now let's vary our composition based on their unit mix.  More Marines? More Banelings.  More Marauders? More Zerglings.  Can't find a good place to engage? Burrow/Drops/Fungal Growth/Wait and Flank.

Here is the key thing, none of this is any assessment of Banelings against Terran, but rather an assessment of the tactics used.

Comment: Nice, haven't checked his economy. He indeed was pretty low on resources in the second part of the game.

Comment: @Tom watch the Day9 video I linked the very first game is a great illustration of what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, have seen that video before. My answers complements, but I agree macro is important too.

Comment: @Tom I don't really agree that is unit composition was poor.  I actually think Bly's unit composition was pretty good, and it was successful a number of times.  He even adjusts his Roaches based on the Marauder play.

Comment: Check the amount of Banelings compared to Speedlings, if he knew about the Marauders (and not to forget the possibility of having a tank in his base) he would've morphed a lot less. He shouldn't have Roaches as they are weak against Marauders, they could be used to counter Reapers early-game but shouldn't be there early-game for any other reasons. Mid-to-end-game they are useful for absorbing damage from Siege Tanks for the primary damage dealers to be able to do there job fine, or he could upgrade Tunneling Claws for greater harassment (minerals, taking out tanks)...

Comment: lol @Oak's edit description.

Comment: @tzenes: Breaking the wall is the only thing he should do with the banelings and not more than that, as it's not worth it with the Marauders around that... Now think about how he can destroy the mineral line when he first needs to break through a wall and get past the Marauders, impossible unless you upgrade. But that would be a wrong decision in his early game as that will not help you counter the Marauders and not to forget a Tank... A bigger army size is always better, but if you ignore that and look what you can do with the same amount of resources then his unit composition was bad.

Comment: @Tom If it was so bad, how did he take the natural?  How did he set Tarson back so well?  No I don't agree.  I also don't agree that busting is the only thing he should use Banelings for.  Even if they were fighting in open field, Banelings provide an important role, reducing the high dps Marines.  But we've gotten into a discussion and to go further is beyond the scope of what we should be talking about in comments.

Comment: @Tom Marauders don't do a ton of DPS on their own you need Marines to make them effective.  This is where the Banelings come in...  Dealing with pure Marauder builds is so much easier than dealing with Marauder/Marine.  I feel like I'm watching a different game from you.  I see banelinge/roach/ling push against MMM success.  Then a series of busts into the main with progressively less success until he gets over run.  I see him doing well in each battle, but dealing with a progressively larger Terran force with a consistently sized Zerg one.

Comment: @tzenes: +1, thank you for your insights. Bly probably felt like "I destroyed his exp, I can (must) kill him immediately!", so he just massed zerglings/banelings hoping it would do the trick. I don't have enough rep to edit your post, but you have written "Now let's very our composition...". Maybe you meant "Now let's vary our composition..."?

Comment: With your last answer on the Bridge chat, I agree. It was solely due to incorrect use and a bad economy...

Comment: @TomWij: I would like to see that answer...

Comment: [His answer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/120684#120684), my agreement is a bit below and if you click the reply icon you can see the conversation.

Comment: Completely agree with this. Once lost the same way. Only got further in tech. Constantly trained mutas, harassed his economy (but never got ahead) and once his economy was down completely, I got steamrolled with thors+marines.

Answer (score 10):

- **No second scout**, he doesn't know what the opponent is doing between 05:00 and 10:00.

  He has enough supply at that point, so it wouldn't be a problem sending an overlord to scout.
- **Two tech labs are seen**, those aren't for Reapers as he hasn't sent any, so... Marauders!

  Which leads us to the next problem:
- **[Incorrect use of Banelings](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/too-much-banelings)**, as he is building Marauders.

  Useful for breaking the wall and killing a lot of marines, but a problem with Marauders and Tanks.
- **What if he had a tank behind his base army?** Think about that, another reason to scout... ;-)
- **No expansion past natural**, if he had one he would have more resources, units, ...

  Not to forget the rule of thumb for Zerg to always have one more expansion than their opponent.

---

So, as for rushing the front, that might not be the best option in this match.

It's better to **let him turtle and deny his natural**, wait for him to come out perhaps, other options:

- Buried units that enter his base and attack the mineral line.
- Overlord to drop his units in the mineral line, or a Nydus Worm (but not on this map).
- Mutalisks to harass the mineral line.
- ...

---

> I don't want to flame, but I just find the Marauders too strong.
>     They are almost perfect counter against Banelings, ...

Yes, hit F12, Zerg Units, Banelings and check Weak Against. Check the same for Marauders... ;-)

See the last part of Tzenes answer for a more in-depth explanation on them.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would down vote Tom.  He has a lot of good advice in here. I don't agree with it all, but I think a downvote is excessive

Comment: I downvoted him because if the question was: `why did the zerg lose`. An answer that doesn't mention drones is just wrong. In fact all of the other options that he listed are also wrong. Overall lack of understanding is demonstrated.

Comment: @Mark: "What should he have done differently to win that match?" is answered, I indeed didn't check the drones but the reasons I listed are also valid... Why are my other options wrong? Build your opinion about *lack of understanding* please, because now it's just moot.

Comment: So unless you speak up you're saying "he shouldn't be Scouting", "he shouldn't counter Marauders", "he should mass Banelings and lose like he did", "he shouldn't think about the Tank (even when he sees a Teched Fact)", "he shouldn't expand against the rule of thumb", ... [Wrong](http://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @TomWij because the other options you listed are all other ways to attack. I don't know if you've played other RTS before, but one of the first lessons you learn from StarCraft is to never attack someone who's actively defending(well). None of those options you listed would've worked. In fact some of them require tech expenditures that just doesn't make sense. You advocate slow mutas vs a 1 base terran? That's... nonsensical. In fact even expanding would've been the wrong answer.

Comment: @TomWij Zerg would've simply gotten more ground needed to be defended without actually increasing income. The only good answer is to saturate with drones. You gave every other answer except that one, and that shows lack of understanding. There is one caveat though. If the zerg knows he's already lost and needs to do a hail mary to get back into the game, then a cross your fingers expo might be called for. Usually though, if the zerg expos in such a situation the terran would just kill him.

Comment: That's why it are options, you pick the most logical given the situation. An Overlord drop (single upgrade) or Buried units (two upgrades) don't cost much. And the expansion (only costs 300 and you could pay for that if economy was fine) would allow you to do a Nydus Worm (costs more, but is more useful) or Mutalisks (costs more, but is more useful)... I'm pretty sure any of these would've worked as a harass on their Mineral Line, and you have the advantages of the upgrades later on. And you didn't have to give up your whole ground army for that...

Comment: @Mark: Again... I agree with the drones and his economy, but how is that a lack of understanding? Economy is key! But the focus was different when watching his replay, Economy would be the next logical result when he sees and complains that he couldn't succeed. If his Economy was fine, a third expansion (made during his attack against the expansion) wouldn't be a problem to afford and wouldn't be risky...

Comment: What is your economy worth if you don't use it properly, and vice-versa.

Comment: @TomWij dude i'm 100% sure that you've never tried any of what you're talking about nor have ever seen them used in vods before... because it's pretty obvious that they're not valid moves. you realize that marines can shoot overlords right? how the hell are you suppose to drop a 1 base terran? drops only work when 1. the terran has multiple bases that needs to be covered and is distracted or have their army somehow away from their base, 2. mid to late game so that even if some ols die on the way in, you still get some of your ground army inside

Comment: 3. when you have excess troops. in this case the units are needed to deny the natural. regarding your other options... just take it from me that the timings and the numbers don't make sense. if i were tenezes i would make some charts... but meh. if you're really curious about this you can ask on teamliquid where i'm sure they'll really give you an answer you can understand, as well as call you some names besides.

Comment: "you realize that marines can shoot overlords right?" They are at the front, so you can drop your stuff at the back right next or into the mineral line and then use your overlord to scout the rest of his base, it will die but that's not a problem given his supply amount. As for reason 3, mass producing units is a strong property of Zerg, so creating excess troops (for which he has the supply) is not a problem either... Well, Tzenes may feel free to do so, but I don't see why it should be taken elsewhere because you think my answer is [Wrong](http://xkcd.com/386/) and can't explain it yourself.

Comment: @TomWij because explaining is hard work. and as the really old comic points out, really a waste of time. on tl someone with a red name would tell you to stop arguing (they only let high level players post on help threads on tl). also the answer really is... play the game and it'll become obvious. i've figuratively seen this situation a billion times in vods and in game and can tell you scientifically that overlord drops/buried roaches/slow mutas, are all wrong. Also i've never seen offensive burrrowed roaches ever work vs t in a high level game. and usually slow mutas are fail.

Comment: Explaining helps one learn things, so I wouldn't consider it a waste of time. If you rather call it arguing, go ahead but that's not my point... Burrowed roaches aren't useless, you could send in a single one to check for detection and if he doesn't have that you could send in more. If you can't get in the roaches are still usefull (burrowed) for preventing his expansion... If you have the chance to take down his economy you should check if it is possible and do it, by pulling back your roaches and not using them you are wasting them and thus wasting resources you decided to spent.

Comment: You've seen a lot of VODs and yet can't show one? If it were so obvious, why is it so hard to prove?

Comment: @TomWij it's because only high level players don't do things that are wrong, and that's why it's hard to find vods of players doing the wrong thing and failing. However I remember 2 vods from SC1 which features progamers doing all ins and dying. PvZ: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCWuEznSMM0&feature=player_embedded and tvz http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0g0wZ1HFv0 yeah, the games are different and the races are different, but fundamentals are the same and if you don't understand why that is then i'm really not going to respond again.

Comment: You're ignoring my first comment, so you agree with it? Even high level players can improve. And I don't see how your VODs are related to this discussion, how are burrowed roaches an all-in in the context of Paja's replay? Now we're suddenly talking about fundamentals too? Did I ever state they were not the same? Why are you trying to change subject and stop a discussion because you want to be right?

Comment: @TomWij: +1, thank you for your ideas. I especially like the idea about forcing him to turtle and deny his expansion, which could be manageable in the Bly's position. Although he won't be able to deny his natural for too long, I think it would buy him enough time to over-macro him. Trying to break into the Tarson's base was probably mistake, since it is just too hard to do some significant damage in the maze of terran buildings, which provide the much-needed cover for marines and marauders.